# JQuery Pagination With Dynamic Loading

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I'm currently creating a website for a friend of mine, and he wants a "Blog" type of system on the front page, which is fine by me, i'll be able to do that.

I'm currently using the [Pagination Class](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2011/10/23/php-pagination-class-updated-version-2/) slightly modified to remove the "All" option (And needless output related to it).

However, I would like to be able to Dynamically load each page instead of redirecting to each page (If a re-write of the Pagination class is required i won't mind doing it, as long as I can get a general concept of how to do it...)

Solutions like [JPaginate](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2011/10/23/php-pagination-class-updated-version-2/) Won't work for me, because in the end, the page could be loading huge amounts of text (The message body is stored in a LargeText table) and i don't want to have all the articles in the source code (Previous experience such as that has actually taught me loading that much text into a web browser is not the smartest thing)

A few things to note, the connection is MySQLi (The Pagination class only appends the limit code for Sql), I don't know much Javascript, and i still consider myself a noob at php.

Comment: `LIMIT` is MySQL (All flavours of connector). Other RDBMS use different syntax eg MS's T-SQL uses `TOP` eg `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM ...`

Comment: I was just pointing out that the Pagination class i was using had nothing to do with SQL other then the LIMIT portion of the syntax, because other solutions i've seen seem to want to generate the SQL Syntax in the code itself....

Comment: Ah, ok :) My misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html

Comment: First link is an old version of the second link, and the second link requires a subscription for the download, which is required for some of the php code...Which i don't really want to have to subscribe to just to get the code...   Thanks for the effort tho (:

Comment: Third last line of code for load_data.php.... "//Some Code. Available in download script"

Comment: Simple example for you to understand the concept - http://www.99points.info/2010/05/ajax-pagination-create-ajax-pagination-using-php-jquery-and-ajax/

Comment: Ill try that out later, i've moved off the blog for now, and working on other stuff.